# Cannot serialize member in IIS7

Tags: .net, iis, web

I have a dot.net project, it has a .asmx file. when I publish it get in error like this.

```
Cannot serialize member <<xxxxx.Entity.Series.pidata>> of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], because it implements IDictionary.
```

if I publish it another pc it will work fine.

**UPDATE :** 
[image]

Comment: What are the IIS and .NET Versions of the PCs?

Comment: iis v 6.1 / .net framework v 4.5.2

Comment: Ok. Read this: http://web.archive.org/web/20100703052446/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psheill/archive/2005/04/09/406823.aspx. There are some problems serializing IDictionary with an XMLSerializer as you message states it. The link will help :)

Comment: @MABVT Thank you.. 
in case iis sever has work and other has not work :(

Comment: Did you try the solution on the non-working server? Since you created the server web application/site twice: Did you select equal settings (Equal file type handlers, equal AppPool .NET versions)?